# How to write a function in Haskell that returns all combinations of 5-card hands than can be taken from a given deck of cards

Tags: haskell

I'm not very experienced with programming and I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out.
I have the types:

```
newtype Hand = Hand { unHand :: [Card] } deriving (Eq, Show)
type Deck = [Card]
```

I want to write a function `allHands` such that it returns all possible combinations of 5 cards that can be taken from a given deck.

```
allHands :: Deck -> [Hand]  
allHands deck = combs 5 deck
```

where `combs :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]` is a function I made that returns all  the possible combinations that can be formed by taking n elements from a list.

My function doesn't work because the result of my function `(combs 5 deck )` is `[[Card]]` and I want it to be `[Hand]`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How doesn't it work? What error are you seeing? Questions asking "why isn't this code working" need a description of a specific problem or error. If `deck :: [Card]` then `map`ping `Hand :: [Card] -> Hand` over `combs 5 deck :: [[Card]]` should have the type `[Hand]`. It should work, so it's impossible to tell what problem you're encountering from the current description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it.

```
allHands deck = map Hand (combs 5 deck)
```

Here's my original answer which probably doesn't do what you want (because it generates duplicates):

```
import Data.List (permutations)

allHands = map Hand . map (take 5) . permutations
```

Comment: What does this do when there are more than 5 cards in the deck? Are the hands distinct?

Comment: @Cirdec good point. there will be duplicates with this approach, but the requirements didn't say they must be unique ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Data.List subsequences

```
allHands = filter ((5==).length) . subsequences
```

Comment: This is one way to implement `combs`. It may take a very very long time to calculate all small hands of a medium-sized deck this way.